# unset shipping and recalculate totals in magento

Tags: php, magento

Here is my problem:

When I add an E-course (no shipping) and a regular product (has shipping) to my cart and select shipping during checkout the cost gets set in the quote.  if I leave checkout after this has been set and then remove the product that has shipping, the shipping cost is still set in the quote and I can't unset it...even by removing all items in the quote.

I'm trying to figure out how to unset the shipping method and recalculate the totals after a product is removed from the cart.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few things are cached in Quote and Shipping Address model, so you have to do this to make Magento recalculate totals if you change qoute items or shipping:

```
    $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_all');
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
    $quote->collectTotals();
```

It worked for me. Magento normally redirects the customer to the cart or to another page after any quote change, so normally it has to calculate totals once per page load.

Comment: I am also looking to clear the shipping and handling from the cart (as shipping is set in OneStepCheckout module after the cart). Where abouts do I put the code you posted?

Comment: if you are programmatically clearing quote after placing an order then you should also set `is_active` flag to `false`

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it programmatically then you can try this:

```
$quote->collectTotals()
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals()
```